# Can I set JFrame's normal size while it is maximized?

Tags: java, swing

**GOAL:**

I'd like to have a frame visible in `Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH` state, but I also want it to have a predefined normal size so when the user un-maximizes it, the frame will resize to the size I want it to be. And I want the frame to first appear maximized, **without a visual resize**. And I want the frame to **remain maximized** until the user un-maximizes it.

**Things that I've tried so far:**

**1)**

```
frame.setExtendedState( Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
frame.setVisible( true );
frame.setSize( 500, 500 );
```

*Evaluation:* The frame will switch to normal state (will not remain maximized) => not good.

**2)**

```
frame.setSize( 500, 500 );
frame.setExtendedState( Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
frame.setVisible( true );
```

*Evaluation:* The window (or just its frame) will appear with a size of 500x500, and after that a visual resize (to maximum) will be visible => not good.
The reason for this is that if a frame is not visible, calling `setExtendedState()` will be deferred until the frame is visible.

**3)**

```
frame.setSize( 500, 500 );
frame.setVisible( true );
frame.setExtendedState( Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
```

*Evaluation:* just like in attempt #2, the frame will have a visual resize => not good.

**4)**
I've tried to add a component listener to the frame overriding `componentResize()` and change state there. I've also tried adding a window state listener overriding `windowStateChange()`. I've also tried adding a window listener overriding `windowOpened()`.

*Evaluation:* All resulted in a visual resize just like in attempt #2 => not good.

So what can I do if I want my frame to have a predefined normal size, but I want it to appear maximized?

EDIT: edited the whole question to be more clear, and added example codes (SSCCE).

Comment: no ideas without posting an SSCCE, btw JFrame.pack() do the same

Comment: @mKorbel calling pack() results in the same: I will see a visual window resize which I want to avoid.

Comment: did you give it a try to let the EDT sleep for a short period and directly invoke your resizes? may not work though, but maybe its worth a try. ugly workarounds sometimes solve ugly problems ;)

Comment: @Zhedar Problem is that I want the frame to remain maximized. Any time I call a setSize(), the frame will automatically switch to NORMAL state from the MAXIMIZED_BOTH state.

Answer (score 3):

Im not sure what you mean so I made an example to demonstrate what I think you would want.

Basically creates a `JFrame` with `setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` and after 5000miliseconds it changes state to `JFrame.NORMAL` with no flickering.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Test {

    public Test() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame() {
            @Override
            public Dimension getPreferredSize() {//used for testing purposes so JFrame has a size
                return new Dimension(300, 300);
            }
        };
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new Timer(5000, new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the frame to remain in MAXIMIZED_BOTH state. I edit the question so things will be more clear.

Comment: *"I want the frame to remain in MAXIMIZED_BOTH state."* So I'm guessing you want to remove the `Timer` used to demonstrate the normal size of the frame?  Leave that part out.

Comment: If I leave that part out, then your proposed solution is already listed in my attempts. It has a problem that I will see a visual resize which I want to avoid.

Comment: @icza after reading your comments etc I think I understand. A big problem though in your sample code is setSize is definitely not recommended. I am not by my PC but as far as I get it you want to set the jframe maximized on creation without the visual flickering? As andrewthompson said just remove the timer. If it still gives visual resize than I do,t thinks its possible to stop. But I'll confirm when, near my pc

Comment: Yes, I want the jframe maximized on creation, but I also want the window to resize to a specified size when the user manually un-maximizes it. If I leave out the setSize(), this is not happen.

Comment: Because setSize is not persistent. You have to override getPreferredSize() or getMinimumSize(). Also I would not recommend setSize for above mentioned problems you should be calling pack() on jframe not setSize.

Comment: @icza Im in front of my PC. I removed `new Timer(...);` and all works perfect when JFrame is created it is maximized and I see no visible resize flickering. Please post SSCCE to show specific problems.

Answer (score 2):

For me the following order works

```
setSize(100,100);
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: he said, he has an **visible** JFrame. yours isnt.

Comment: I wrote in the question that I tried this, and doing this way first the window (or maybe just its frame) will appear in the size you set (100x100 in your example), and then it will be maximized. This is a visual resize which I want to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

You were close to answer in your **#2** attempt. There is the `setMaximizedBounds()` method in `JFrame` class. It is used by frame on `MAXIMIZED_BOTH` extendedState set to show the frame of concrete size without flickering. What works for me:

```
frame.setLocation(location);
frame.setSize( 500, 500 );
frame.setMaximizedBounds(calculateMaximizedBounds(frame))
frame.setExtendedState( Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH );
frame.setVisible( true );
```

`calculateMaximizedBounds()` calculates maximized bounds (thanks, KO!) for frame, depending on current frame location and size - is it important if U have 2+ monitors, especially if they have different dimensions.

Comment: I get the same result whether I include the `setMaximizedBounds()` or not (except that when I include `setMaximizedBounds()` the maximized size will obviously be the one I set).

Comment: Do you mean that frame keeps flickering?

Comment: Yes, the same as without `setMaximizedBounds()`. Although **#2** is the closest to what I want, and it is not even bothering... But I didn't know about `setMaximizedBounds()` so thanks.

Comment: One more PS: the frame should not be visible until `frame.setVisible(true)` called

Comment: Yes, that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {

        @Override
        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                if (e.getNewState() == Frame.NORMAL) {
                    if (getSize().width == 0 || getSize().height == 0) {
                        setSize(500, 500);
                    }
                }
        }
    });
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I start with a maximized frame. And when I un-maximize it, your listener will be called, but `getSize()` will return a size with both width and height greater than 0 so `setSize()` will not be called.

Comment: You can test it. At that time you invoke getSize(), and it will return (0, 0). Becase you invoke frame.setExtendedState( Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH ), and not actually invoke setSize(). So the frame size is (0,0).

Comment: I did test it. And `getSize()` returned me a `Dimension` with something close to my screen resolution.

Comment: You ever invoked setSize()?

Comment: No, I didn't. I just invoked `setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH)` and `setVisible(true)`.

Comment: OK, it's odd. In my pc it's ok, and the getSize() method return (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me. I used Perzers idea of a WindowEvent listener, but I check if window state was changed from maximized, but not minimized (so after restoring the program the full previous state is recovered):

```
    setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e) {
                // In Windows10 state 7 is returned if you minimize, usually ICONIFIED should mean the window is minimized, I used JDK1.6 on W10 (don't ask why)..
                if (e.getNewState() != JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH && e.getNewState() != 7 && e.getNewState() != JFrame.ICONIFIED) {  
                    setSize(768, 500);
                }
        }
    });
    setVisible(true);
```

I'm not sure what is the state 7 actually tho.

UPDATE: Using JDK1.8 in W10 - state here actually is "JFrame.ICONIFIED" as it should be.
State 7 is actually "NE_RESIZE_CURSOR" which is deprecated.
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.awt.Frame